# Best practices including pre-installed data?

Tags: android

Where is the best location to install pre-install data for your app?  (for example, sample photos).

According to this document, we should put data in "/Android/data/your_package_name/files/"

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

I am not 100% sure what should go in that location and what not....

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much answered your own question.
Anything that your application requires that may be too large for the device internal memory is best to be stored on the devices external storage.
You will have to check that external storage is writable and when you come to read it it make sure it exists etc.